# Does facebook opengraph works on localhost?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph, social-likes

Maybe a stupid question but I never integrated social like butons before. I'm using social-likes plugin https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes and I would like to add an image and description via facebook opengraph og tags. Now I did exactly what is described in the docs and placed the og metatags in my head section.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo URL ?>">
<meta property="og:title" content="{Mollamaya">
<meta property="og:description" content="Hier moet een beschrijving komen... ">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo URL ?>public/images/logo/facebook.png">
```

I'm not seeing the image nor any other content from the metatags. Could this be because opengraph does not work on localhost? do I need to load any additional scripts for opengraph to work? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Open Graph requires that a domain should be publicly available. Now, if you're testing Facebook Open graph in localhost, you might need to use [proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/) so that your local server will be publicly available.